# wrong feature_names in scikit tfidfvectorizer

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf

I'm trying to use tfidfvectorizer of scikit-learn but if I don't limit the max_feature (to something like 50) the feature_names are gonna be like u'00 00 9510477781' 
when I set max_features=50 or less it shows feature_names correclty (u'me' or u'book' , ...)

```
test_tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1,2), min_df = 1, stop_words = 'english',max_features=50)
test_tfidf_matrix =  test_tf.fit_transform(test_corpus)
feature_names = test_tf.get_feature_names()
```

am I doing it wrong ?
p.s I'm using python 2.7

Comment: This does not sound like an error to me, when you limit your features, the vectorizer will keep the e.g. 50 most important features, thus, in a text corpus, it is usual for them to be whole words and the numerical parts, or very frequently used words like 'the', 'a',  to be cut off. It all depends on what your test_corpus consists of. Does your corpus contain '9510477781' etc.?

Comment: Nope, its mostly texts, at least some feature_names should be words but its all numbers in unicode when max feature is not set

Comment: Oh, I haven't realized you meant that all feature names are like this. Scikit-learn version?

Comment: It's 0.18.1, I think it might be a memory issue, although I've 8gb of Ram and its not used that much

Comment: Hmm that's weird.. And I cannot find a way to reproduce it...